# AttributeError: Unknown property tick_label

Tags: python

I just want to make a Histogram which I can make Abscissa personally.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
heros=['Mage','Priest','Warlock']
y=[0.1828, 0.1300, 0.0689]

x = range(len(heros))
plt.bar(range(len(y)), y,color=['g'],tick_label=heros)
plt.show()
```

But I got an error----
AttributeError: Unknown property tick_label

Comment: Thats interesting. I am unable to reproduce this error. Your code runs fine on my python interpreter. Which version of python and matplotlib are you using, and in what kind of an environment are you running this (e.g. terminal, iPython, etc.)

Comment: reproducible in python 2.7.10;  matplotlib.__version__
'1.3.1'

Comment: @downshift with what version of MPL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely using a fairly old (pre-November 2015) version of Matplotlib. The `tick_label` argument was [added to `ax.bar` in 1.5.0](https://matplotlib.org/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_1.5.html#plot-bar-and-barh-with-labels) with [this commit](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/commit/c2a6da5153e1d57dcfc7cb4985a7089d068bf0b3#diff-5413f0a8bf90b52c89b3470d9b9507d0).

Update to a newer version (2.1 is release-candidate status right now!) or rewrite the ticks manually by modifying the axis's tick labels. 1.4 and earlier example [here](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.2/examples/lines_bars_and_markers/barh_demo.html), excerpted below:

```
# Example data
people = ('Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Slim', 'Jim')
y_pos = np.arange(len(people))
performance = 3 + 10 * np.random.rand(len(people))

plt.barh(y_pos, performance, align='center', alpha=0.4)
plt.yticks(y_pos, people)
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
    plot.xticks(x, heroes)
```

instead